# asp.net core 1.0 publishing to IIS 7.5

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-7.5, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created simple ASP.NET core 1.0 application with Individual user account authentication setting. If I run using IIS express it runs fine.

[image]

I am following this article https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html to deploy application to IIS

On browsing, I get below error-

[image]

This is added into my  **ConfigureServices** method of startup.

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>

            {

                options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = false;

                options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;

                options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;

            });
```

**Project.json**

```
{

  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-ASPNet_Core1_461_6sep-9ce5b13e-6499-42b3-bf79-944ffded008c",



  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {

      "version": "1.0.0",

      "type": "platform"

    },

    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {

      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

      "type": "build"

    },

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {

      "version": "1.0.0",

      "type": "build"

    },

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {

      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

      "type": "build"

    },

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {

      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

      "type": "build"

    },

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc":  {

      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

      "type": "build"

    }

  },



  "tools": {

    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {

      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

      "imports": [

        "portable-net45+win8"

      ]

    }

  },



  "frameworks": {

    "netcoreapp1.0": {

      "imports": [

        "dotnet5.6",

        "portable-net45+win8"

      ]

    }

  },



  "buildOptions": {

    "emitEntryPoint": true,

    "preserveCompilationContext": true

  },



  "runtimeOptions": {

    "configProperties": {

      "System.GC.Server": true

    }

  },



  "publishOptions": {

    "include": [

      "wwwroot",

      "Views",

      "Areas/**/Views",

      "appsettings.json",

      "web.config"

    ]

  },



  "scripts": {

    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],

    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]

  }

}
```

Any additional step required other than following above mentioned article?

My environment is-
VS 2015 professional update 3, 
Windows 7 OS, 
IIS 7.5

Thanks & Regards
Vishal